# Ошибка создания непривилегированного контейнера в lxc

Tags: linux, debian, lxc

Система:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-4-686-pae

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie)
Release:    8.9
Codename:   jessie
```

Настройки lxc (v1.0.6):

```
$ cat ~/.config/lxc/default.conf 
lxc.include = /etc/lxc/default.conf
lxc.id_map = u 0 1345184 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 1345184 65536
```

При попытке создать контейнер пишет:

```
$ lxc-create -t download -n test1
unshare: Operation not permitted
read pipe: No such file or directory
lxc_container: Failed to chown container dir
lxc_container: Error creating container test1
```

Как починить?

Answer (score 0):

## Руководство по созданию непривилегированных контейнеров lxc (в процессе написания)

### Требования

#### Пользовательское пространство имён (subuid, subgid)

Необходимо наличие выделенных ID для пользователей и групп `/etc/subuid` и `/etc/subgid`, соответственно, что позволит отображать PID процессов контейнера в реальные PID хоста, доступные (выделенные) данному пользователю.

Их наличие для пользователя можно проверить данной командой:

```
$ grep -rne "$(whoami)" /etc/subuid /etc/subgid
```

вывод будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
/etc/subuid:21:edem:1345184:65536
/etc/subgid:21:edem:1345184:65536
```

Если же таких записей нет, то их необходимо будет добавить, где число после имени пользователя вычисляется по формуле: последнее-число последней строки в файле /etc/subuid + 65535; для /etc/subgid аналогично.

Это можно сделать как вручную, отредактировав вышеупомянутые файлы, так и с помощью команды:

```
# LAST_SUBID=$(tail -n 1 /etc/subuid | awk -F: '{print $2}'); \
   usermod --add-subuids $LAST_SUBID-`expr $LAST_SUBID + 65535` $USERNAME
```